# Installing cosmos db emulator SSL certificate in docker redhat/kafka-connect container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka-connect, self-signed-certificate, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I did the setup of the Cosmos DB emulator on the local machine, and started with the following parameters:

```
/port=443 /AllowNetworkAccess /Key=<CosmosPrimaryKey>
```

And currently, it is accessible via `https://<LocalMachineIP>/`

When I tried to make a curl request from the docker Redhat container (using docker image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect) it throws the below error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

And when trying to crate cosmos DB source connector it throws the below error:

```
   [20 10:37:45,018] ERROR Client initialization failed. Check if the endpoint is reachable and if your auth token is valid. More info: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-service-unavailable-java (com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl)
    
    [2022-05-20 10:37:45,079] ERROR unexpected failure in initializing client. (com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl)
    
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Client initialization failed. Check if the endpoint is reachable and if your auth token is valid. More info: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-service-unavailable-java
    
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.initializeGatewayConfigurationReader(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:401)
    
    .......
    
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    
    [2022-05-20 10:37:45,095] WARN [8e2a220b, L:/172.25.0.6:57076 ! R:/192.168.154.131:443] The connection observed an error (reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect)
    
    shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    
    at shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:477)
    
    ..........
    
    at shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    
    at shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    
    at shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    
   .........
    at shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1283)
    
    at shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
    
    at shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
    
    ... 17 more
    
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    
   .....................
    
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335)
    
    ... 31 more
    
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    
    ... 37 more
```

I have exported the cosmos emulator .cer file using [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator-export-ssl-certificates).

How to install it in the Docker container "kafka-connect"?

Comment: They are no different than other files. You would use `COPY` in your Dockerfile to add cert files.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your curl request?
You need to use the -k flag to denote that it’s insecure.

```
curl -k https://{emulatoripaddr}:8081/_explorer/emulator.pem > emulatorcert.crt
```

It needs to be  .crt
Then copy it to

```
/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
```

Then install it

```
update-ca-certificates
```

Additionally you can mount a volume to the cosmos folder and save the .pem manually… /tmp/cosmos/appdata